# PHP JSON value if exist then

Tags: php, json

I have a small JSON file and want to check if "fullday":"no" is in a object. If this is true it needs to output no.

How can I do this with PHP?

```
 {
    "calendar": {
        "title": "Agenda punten",
        "agenda": [
            {
                "id":1,
                "datum": "2015-07-13",
                "title": "Titel agendapunt #1",
                "beschrijving": "Dit is een beschrijving",
                "fullday": "no"
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "datum": "2015-07-14",              
                "title": "Titel agendapunt #2",
                "beschrijving": "Dit is een beschrijving", 
                "fullday": "yes"                                    
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: I tried to find tut's about this but can't find anything.

Comment: Any code you have tried??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?php
$json='{
    "calendar": {
                    "title": "Agenda punten",
                    "agenda": [

            {       "id":1,
                    "datum": "2015-07-13",
                    "title": "Titel agendapunt #1",
                    "beschrijving": "Dit is een beschrijving",
                    "fullday": "no"
            },
            {       "id":2,
                    "datum": "2015-07-14",              
                    "title": "Titel agendapunt #2",
                    "beschrijving": "Dit is een beschrijving", 
                    "fullday": "yes"                                    
            }
        ]
    }
}';

$data=json_decode($json,true);
$getdata=$data['calendar']['agenda'];

foreach($getdata as $value)
{
    if($value['fullday']=='no')
    {
        echo 'Title:'.$value['title'].'</br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer-> Title:Titel agendapunt #1

Comment: I have posted my answer check it and let me know